# Python3 Selenium проблема с javascript на странице ip-камеры

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, chromedriver

У ip-камеры есть javascript функция `snapshot`:

```
<a href="#" target="_self" onclick="javaScript:snapshot('/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264'); return false;"><img src="/pics/button_shot_27x27px.gif" width="27" height="27" border="0" title="Snapshot" alt="Snapshot"></a>
```

я пытаюсь сделать запрос с помощью Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://172.16.160.73/')
driver.execute_script("snapshot('/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264');")
```

Но получаю ощибку что нет такого скрипта.

Я исследовал страницу открытую через selenium(driver) и обнаружил вот такие вот строки (в обычных браузерах этих строчек и этого кода нету):

```
<noscript>
Your browser has JavaScript turned off.<br>For the user interface to work, you must enable JavaScript in your browser and reload/refresh this page.
</noscript>
```

И последующий HTML-код отличный от обычного который я вижу в стандартном браузере. Пытался всячески "включить" javascript, но безуспешно.
В открытой selenium`ом вкладке все как в обычном браузере (жмется открывается, скриншоты делаются, видеопоток идет). Подскажите это защита такая? или я что то не так делаю?
Камера AXIS Q6032-E Network Camera

Comment: Благодоря @vladimir-t вопрос немного изменился: Проблема в том что в page source сплошной js и изначально функции snapshot там нету, вот [код страницы камеры](https://pastebin.com/33GyTmvh). Я пробовал ждать и руками(python console), и sleep. но Пока безуспешно. Можно ли из selenium или bs4 работать не с page source, а с загруженной страницей?

Comment: Обновил ответ со ссылкой на API вашей камеры:
https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, похоже, что вы не заметили эту строчку при обычном просмотре, но она всё-таки там есть - проверьте ещё раз. Эта строка просто работает только при отсутствии JS, но в коде страницы она есть всегда. Даже в stackoverflow вы можете её сейчас увидеть, если посмотрите код страницы (не inspect, а именно "код страницы").

Selenium по умолчанию поддерживает JS, и как раз, чтобы выключить его, нужны определённые манипуляции.

Надо помнить, что JS - язык асинхорнный по дизайну, и некоторые события происходят после определённого ожидания (иногда динамически подгружаются скрипты, некоторые функции требуют времени, срабатывают только после полной загрузки страницы, создают другие функции и т.д.), поэтому я бы вам советовал для начала использовать простое внешнее ожидание после загрузки страницы (перед выполнением js-кода):

```
sleep(10)
```

Потом, когда захочется выполнить более точное ожидание, то выбирайте событие, которое вам необходимо и ожидайте (будет действовать для всех вызовов внутри вашего инстанса driver):

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

К примеру, если там работает jQuery, то можете использовать:

```
driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0")
```

Подробнее по jQuery:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953967/using-selenium-wait-until-to-wait-some-query-finished-in-python

!!! **UPD после комментариев** - в вашем случае вам вообще нужен только скриншот (изображение), поэтому получайте его используя не javascript:snapshot, а родной API вашей камеры (используя обычный get):

```
http://axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?date=1&clock=1&camera=[CHANNEL]&resolution=[WIDTH]x[HEIGHT]
```

https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Axis

Comment: Да действитеьлно вы правы, моя оплошность. Но я честно говоря не знал, что inspect-режим отличается от page source. Итак я обнаружил что страница в page source - сплошной js. Я не силен в js. [исходный код страницы камеры](https://pastebin.com/33GyTmvh) . Если я правильно понял, то bs4 и Селениум работают именно с page source, как работать уже с загруженной страницей. sleep пробовал - безуспешно.

Comment: Спасибо, но с page source оно не совсем так - page source это то, что отдаёт сервер. Inspect - это DOM модель, которую построил в итоге браузер.
Eё можно получить так:
innerHTML = driver.execute_script("return document.body")